# NLog is not writing debug events to the log

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the following appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Trace"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbDatabase": "Server=aaaa-aaaa;Database=fffff;uid=fffff;pwd=fffff;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "wwwww",
    "Issuer": "Test.com"
  }
}
```

And my Program.cs looks like this

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
```

And my nlog.config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Trace" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Trace" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

However when I call `_logger.LogDebug("test");` from my code it does not get written to the logs.

If I call `_logger.LogError("test");` it does get written.

What is going on. It is clearly a logging level issue but I have set all the settings to Trace!

Comment: Have you checked other appsettings files, like appsettings.Development.json?

Comment: There is no development.json just the standard appsettings.json and appsetting.release.json. I am running in debug mode so that will not be used,

Answer (score 0):

In appsettings.json you define namespace which should be logged.

For example:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
     "MyNameSpace" : "Information"}}
```

Comment: Surely the default would be used if no specific namespace is listed? I have never needed to do that before.

Comment: Maybe change maxLevel from Trace to Debug in nLog configuartion. You have same min and max level.

Comment: I have tried changing the max levels to Error but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my machine and all of a sudden the debug level logs started appearing!

No idea what on earth was going on.

Comment: Glad it has been resolved. For this case I recommend to remove the question. It's confusing if we can't reproduce it.  Im sure NLog isn't doing things differently after a reboot